# variable does not live long enough when storing a csv::DecodedRecords iterator

Tags: csv, rust, lifetime

I'm trying to create an iterator trait that provides a specific type of resource, so I can implement multiple source types. I'd like to create a source for reading from a CSV file, a binary etc..

I'm using the `rust-csv` library for deserializing CSV data:

```
#[derive(RustcDecodable)]
struct BarRecord {
    bar: u32
}

trait BarSource : Iterator {}

struct CSVBarSource {
    records: csv::DecodedRecords<'static, std::fs::File, BarRecord>,
}

impl CSVBarSource {
    pub fn new(path: String) -> Option<CSVBarSource> {
        match csv::Reader::from_file(path) {
            Ok(reader) => Some(CSVBarSource { records: reader.decode() }),
            Err(_) => None
        }
    }
}

impl Iterator for CSVBarSource {
    type Item = BarRecord;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<BarRecord> {
        match self.records.next() {
            Some(Ok(e)) => Some(e),
            _ => None
        }
    }
}
```

I cannot seem to store a reference to the `DecodedRecords` iterator returned by the CSV reader due to lifetime issues:

> error: reader does not live long enough

How can I store a reference to the decoded records iterator and what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the documentation, [`Reader::decode` is defined as](http://burntsushi.net/rustdoc/csv/struct.Reader.html#method.decode):

```
fn decode<'a, D: Decodable>(&'a mut self) -> DecodedRecords<'a, R, D>
```

That is `reader.decode()` cannot outlive `reader` (because of `'a`).
And with this declaration:

```
struct CSVBarSource {
    records: csv::DecodedRecords<'static, std::fs::File, BarRecord>,
                              // ^~~~~~~
}
```

`reader` would need a `'static` lifetime, that is it would need to live forever, which it does not hence the error you get “`reader` does not live long enough”.

You should store `reader` directly in `CSVBarSource`:

```
struct CSVBarSource {
    reader: csv::Reader<std::fs::File>,
}
```

And call `decode` only as needed.