# Can I use a mutable reference method like a value-passing one?

Tags: rust, lifetime, borrow-checker

Can I use a mutable reference method like a value-passing one? For example, can I use

```
o.mth(&mut self, ...)
```

as

```
o.mth(self, ...)
```

This would allow me to return the result without worrying about the lifetime of `o`. It might involve a `move` closure, or some kind of wrapper?

For context, I'm trying to return a boxed iterator over CSV records using the rust-csv package but the iterator can't outlive the reader, which [`Reader::records(&'t mut self)`](http://burntsushi.net/rustdoc/csv/struct.Reader.html#method.records) borrows mutably. Contrast this with [`BufRead::lines(self)`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/io/trait.BufRead.html#method.lines), which consumes its reader and hence can be returned without lifetime problems.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/36645452/155423, http://stackoverflow.com/q/30488928/155423, http://stackoverflow.com/q/38797960/155423 — for whatever reason, everyone wants to return a CSV iterator.

Comment: Since the iterator elements aren't borrowed, it looks like the records iterator could be remade to take a `R: Read` by value. Since `&mut R` implements `Read where R: Read`, it covers both the cases.

Comment: @bluss Yeah, I was surprised by that. I assumed they would be string slices. Such a change would still be a breaking API change though, but not one that's terrible to adapt to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you cannot. The reason that `self`, `&self`, and `&mut self` methods exist is because they behave differently, have different restrictions, and allow different things.

In this case, you'd probably ultimately end up trying [to create an iterator that yields references to itself](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25702909/155423), which isn't allowed, or [store a value and a reference to that value in the same struct](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32300132/155423), which is also disallowed.